# How to implement filter search/listview search?

Tags: android, android-listview

How do I make use of the current `ListView` to integrate with my search?

```
/** 
 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView 
 * */
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( 
AllEventsActivity.this, eventsList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_EID, _NAME}, 
new int[] { R.id.eid, R.id.ename }); 

//updating listview 
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Now how do I use the `ListView` to integrate into my search code below?

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
    textlength = et.getText().length();
    array_sort.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < listview_array.length; i++) {
        if (textlength <= listview_array[i].length()) {
            if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)
                             listview_array[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
            {
                array_sort.add(listview_array[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListViewSearchExample.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you seem to miss is:

declare your adapter as a variable and call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```